# Pass Function to reduce duplicate code

Tags: csv, parsing, f#, encapsulation

I'm trying to learn F# and I feel like I can write / rewrite this block of code to be more "idiomatic" F# but I just can't figure out how I can accomplish it.

My simple program will be loading values from 2 csv files: A list of Skyrim potion effects, and a list of Skyrim Ingredients. An ingredient has 4 Effects. Once I have the Ingredients, I can write something to process them - right now, I just want to write the CSV load in a way that makes sense.

**Code**

Here are my types:

```
type Effect(name:string, id, description, base_cost, base_mag, base_dur, gold_value) =
    member this.Name = name
    member this.Id = id
    member this.Description = description
    member this.Base_Cost = base_cost
    member this.Base_Mag = base_mag
    member this.Base_Dur = base_dur
    member this.GoldValue = gold_value

type Ingredient(name:string, id, primary, secondary, tertiary, quaternary, weight, value) =
    member this.Name = name
    member this.Id = id
    member this.Primary = primary
    member this.Secondary = secondary
    member this.Tertiary = tertiary
    member this.Quaternary = quaternary
    member this.Weight = weight
    member this.Value = value
```

Here is where I parse an individual comma-separated string, per type:

```
let convertEffectDataRow (csvLine:string) =
    let cells = List.ofSeq(csvLine.Split(','))
    match cells with
    | name::id::effect::cost::mag::dur::value::_ ->            
        let effect = new Effect(name, id, effect, Decimal.Parse(cost), Int32.Parse(mag), Int32.Parse(dur), Int32.Parse(value))
        Success effect
    | _ -> Failure "Incorrect data format!"


let convertIngredientDataRow (csvLine:string) =
    let cells = List.ofSeq(csvLine.Split(','))
    match cells with
        | name::id::primary::secondary::tertiary::quaternary::weight::value::_ ->
            Success (new Ingredient(name, id, primary, secondary, tertiary, quaternary, Decimal.Parse(weight), Int32.Parse(value)))
        | _ -> Failure "Incorrect data format!"
```

So I *feel* like I should be able to build a function that accepts one of these functions or chains them or something, so that I can recursively go through the lines in the CSV file and pass those lines to the correct function above. Here is what I've tried so far:

```
type csvTypeEnum = effect=1 | ingredient=2        

let rec ProcessStuff lines (csvType:csvTypeEnum) =
    match csvType, lines with
        | csvTypeEnum.effect, [] -> []
        | csvTypeEnum.effect, currentLine::remaining ->
            let parsedLine = convertEffectDataRow2 currentLine
            let parsedRest = ProcessStuff remaining csvType
            parsedLine :: parsedRest
        | csvTypeEnum.ingredient, [] -> []
        | csvTypeEnum.ingredient, currentLine::remaining ->
            let parsedLine = convertIngredientDataRow2 currentLine
            let parsedRest = ProcessStuff remaining csvType
            parsedLine :: parsedRest
        | _, _ -> Failure "Error in pattern matching"
```

But this (predictably) has a compile error on second instance of recursion and the last pattern. Specifically, the second time `parsedLine :: parsedRest` shows up does not compile. This is because the function is attempting to both return an `Effect` and an `Ingredient`, which obviously won't do.

Now, I could just write 2 entirely different functions to handle the different CSVs, but that feels like extra duplication. This *might* be a harder problem than I'm giving it credit for, but it feels like this should be rather straightforward.

**Sources**

The CSV parsing code I took from chapter 4 of this book: https://www.manning.com/books/real-world-functional-programming

Comment: Do you want to implement this yourself or are you just looking for a solution? The quickest way would be just to use the [CSV Type Provider](http://fsharp.github.io/FSharp.Data/library/CsvProvider.html). You shouldn't need to define an enum, just wrap Effect and Ingredient into CsvType.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the line types aren't interleaved into the same file and they refer to different csv file formats, I would probably not go for a Discriminated Union and instead pass the processing function to the function that processes the file line by line.

In terms of doing things idiomatically, I would use a [Record](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualfsharpdocs/conceptual/records-%5Bfsharp%5D) rather than a standard .NET class for this kind of simple data container.  Records provide automatic equality and comparison implementations which are useful in F#.

You can define them like this:

```
type Effect = {
    Name : string; Id: string; Description : string; BaseCost : decimal; 
    BaseMag : int; BaseDuration : int; GoldValue : int
    }

type Ingredient= {
    Name : string; Id: string; Primary: string; Secondary : string; Tertiary : string; 
    Quaternary : string; Weight : decimal; GoldValue : int
    }
```

That requires a change to the conversion function, e.g.

```
let convertEffectDataRow (csvLine:string) =
    let cells = List.ofSeq(csvLine.Split(','))
    match cells with
    | name::id::effect::cost::mag::dur::value::_ ->            
        Success  {Name = name; Id = id; Description = effect;  BaseCost = Decimal.Parse(cost); 
                  BaseMag = Int32.Parse(mag); BaseDuration = Int32.Parse(dur); GoldValue = Int32.Parse(value)}
    | _ -> Failure "Incorrect data format!"
```

Hopefully it's obvious how to do the other one.

Finally, cast aside the `enum` and simply replace it with the appropriate line function (I've also swapped the order of the arguments).

```
let rec processStuff f lines  =
    match lines with
    |[] -> []
    |current::remaining -> f current :: processStuff f remaining
```

The argument `f` is just a function that is applied to each string line.  Suitable `f` values are the functions we created above, e.g.`convertEffectDataRow`. So you can simply call `processStuff convertEffectDataRow` to process an effect file and `processStuff convertIngredientDataRow` to process and ingredients file.

However, now we've simplified the `processStuff` function, we can see it has type: `f:('a -> 'b) -> lines:'a list -> 'b list`.  This is the same as the built-in [`List.map` function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualfsharpdocs/conceptual/list.map%5B't,'u%5D-function-%5Bfsharp%5D) so we can actually remove this custom function entirely and just use `List.map`.

```
let processEffectLines lines = List.map convertEffectDataRow lines

let processIngredientLines lines = List.map convertIngredientDataRow lines
```

Comment: Thank you for the awesome step-by-step! I didn't realize you could pass a function without declaring the arguments or return type (as you did with f), which certainly makes this problem a lot easier.

Answer (score 2):

1. (optional) Convert Effect and Ingredient to records, as s952163 suggested.
2. Think carefully about the return types of your functions. `ProcessStuff` returns a list from one case, but a single item (`Failure`) from the other case. Thus compilation error.
3. You haven't shown what `Success` and `Failure` definitions are. Instead of generic success, you could define the result as

   ```
   type Result = 
     | Effect of Effect 
     | Ingredient of Ingredient 
     | Failure of string
   ```

And then the following code compiles correctly:

```
let convertEffectDataRow (csvLine:string) =
    let cells = List.ofSeq(csvLine.Split(','))
    match cells with
    | name::id::effect::cost::mag::dur::value::_ ->            
        let effect = new Effect(name, id, effect, Decimal.Parse(cost), Int32.Parse(mag), Int32.Parse(dur), Int32.Parse(value))
        Effect effect
    | _ -> Failure "Incorrect data format!"


let convertIngredientDataRow (csvLine:string) =
    let cells = List.ofSeq(csvLine.Split(','))
    match cells with
        | name::id::primary::secondary::tertiary::quaternary::weight::value::_ ->
            Ingredient (new Ingredient(name, id, primary, secondary, tertiary, quaternary, Decimal.Parse(weight), Int32.Parse(value)))
        | _ -> Failure "Incorrect data format!"

type csvTypeEnum = effect=1 | ingredient=2        

let rec ProcessStuff lines (csvType:csvTypeEnum) =
    match csvType, lines with
    | csvTypeEnum.effect, [] -> []
    | csvTypeEnum.effect, currentLine::remaining ->
        let parsedLine = convertEffectDataRow currentLine
        let parsedRest = ProcessStuff remaining csvType
        parsedLine :: parsedRest
    | csvTypeEnum.ingredient, [] -> []
    | csvTypeEnum.ingredient, currentLine::remaining ->
        let parsedLine = convertIngredientDataRow currentLine
        let parsedRest = ProcessStuff remaining csvType
        parsedLine :: parsedRest
    | _, _ -> [Failure "Error in pattern matching"]
```

`csvTypeEnum` type looks fishy, but I'm not sure what you were trying to achieve, so just fixed the compilation errors.

Now you can refactor your code to reduce duplication by passing functions as parameters when needed. But always start with types!

Answer (score 0):

You can  certainly pass a function to another function and use a DU as a return type, for example:

```
type CsvWrapper =
    | CsvA of string
    | CsvB of int

let csvAfunc x =
    CsvA x

let csvBfunc x =
    CsvB x

let csvTopFun x  =
    x 

csvTopFun csvBfunc 5
csvTopFun csvAfunc "x"
```

As for the type definitions, you can just use records, will save you some typing:

```
type Effect = { 
    name:string 
    id: int 
    description: string
}
let eff = {name="X";id=9;description="blah"}
```